# How to upload correctly addon domain with CPanel

Tags: php, laravel, server, cpanel

I've already deployed a laravel project to the server with CPanel. I've transferred all the public files in **websiteA** to the public_html. It works fine. The directory looks like this.

```
/home/tuturu
->public_html
->websiteA
    ->app
    ->vendor
    -> ...
```

Now I'm trying to add an addon domain **websiteB** to the same server. As its a laravel project and want it to be pointing at the public folder, I've seen the root document to be `public_html/websiteB/public`. Now, the directory looks like this:

```
 /home/tuturu
->public_html
    ->websiteB
        ->app
        ->vendor
        ->public
->websiteA
    ->app
    ->vendor
    -> ...
```

I've also changed the index.php inside the public folder to:

```
require __DIR__.'/../public_html/websiteB/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../public_html/websiteB/bootstrap/app.php';
```

but when I go to websiteB, it gives an HTTP 500 error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Having your code in public_html is a bad practice. You should use "Add-on Domains" and point the path to the folder where your index.php file is.

Comment: The problem is, inside public_html has already stored all the public files for websiteA such as htaccess and index.php. Where should i place the public files for websiteB ? @DmitriSandler

Comment: Each site should get its own "Add-On Domain" and its own folder. You can create folders websiteA and websiteB in your home directory (the one containing mail, php, public_ftp, public_html and others). If you have large number of sites you might create a more complex folder structure so you can easily identify (group) your sites. Just don't put it into public_html.

Comment: uwh, so the files in public folder doesn't have to go in public_html ? I can just set the root document to point towards the public folder and that'll work ?

Comment: Laravel's public folder should stay with the application, because files inside public folder use relative path to other files within Laravel's directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder in your home directory for example my_websites:

[image: new folder]

Upload two of your sites to this folder:

[image: add two websites]

Configure your "Add-On Domains" to point to Laravel's public folder for each site:

[image: addon domains document root points to laravels public folder]

Keep in mind that paths are case sensitive on Linux systems.

Comment: I cant specify the document root to /home/tuturu .. the document root default is /public_html/

Comment: That is only true for a main domain. Are you able to add an "Add-On Domain" or a "Subdomain"?